# Xenial checking much fewer apt-get sites

Tags: apt, 16.04

Every since upgrading to 16.04, I've gone from dozens of sites in my `apt-get update`s to 6.  I also get updates much less frequently, so I'm worried something broke.  Is this normal behavior, or did I break something when moving from 15.10 to 16.04.  Below is the output of my `apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                          
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                  
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                              
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Reading package lists... Done 
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Comment: Have you actually checked your defined sources, either by looking under /etc or through Synaptic or similar? It's normal for an upgrade to disable third-party sources, but whether that's your problem or not depends on whether you had these in the first place...

Comment: Third-party sources, sure, and I did have some of those. But it looks like it's not even checking as many ubuntu.com sources as I'm used to seeing. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not wrong. Ubuntu is maturing.

```
<yoda>Will you, less sources, see henceforth</yoda>
```

As per the [Release notes of Xenial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes), some packages/repos were dropped.

> **Updated Packages**
>
> As with every new release, packages--applications and
>   software of all kinds--are being updated at a rapid pace. Many of
>   these packages came from an automatic sync from Debian's unstable
>   branch; others have been explicitly pulled in for Ubuntu 16.04.